# How to fix JQuery DataTables mData error on table with html

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I used following HTML table to paginate using jquery datatables

```
<table class="table table-responsive dataTable" id="products-table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Image</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Jarti</th>
        <th>Wages</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th class="no-sort">Status</th>
        <th colspan="3" class="no-sort">Action</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
                 <img src="/images/designs/4.JPG" style="width:120px;" class="img img-responsive" alt="Gold Ring">
            </td>
            <td>RRS</td>
            <td>0.00000</td>
            <td>0.00000</td>
            <td>0.00000</td>
            <td>0.00000</td>
            <td>
                  <span for="" class="label label-warning">In Progress</span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST" action="/products/3" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="5fkON57zDrYwdBZjL5PHjNfi1cgFQhkTg5laynQ6">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="/products/3" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
                    <a href="/products/3/edit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, this table have HTML tags. I used following JS to paginate:

```
$('.table').DataTable();
```

Here while implementing the above JS I'm getting error:

> Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

How can I resolve this? Any help/suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid HTML markup for jQuery DataTables.

First, there should be at least one column in the header for each column in the table body, see [complex header example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html). You need to either remove `colspan` and replace it with individual `th` elements or add another row of header columns with `th` element for each column in the body.

Secondly, there is a mismatch between number of header columns (`10`) and and number of columns in the body (`9`).

As a side note I would avoid initializing DataTables by class name `.table` and use element id `#products-table` in case you have other tables with the same class that you don't want to initialize as DataTables.

See [corrected example](http://jsfiddle.net/xohjtns6/) for code and demonstration.